# How can I parse this string that's similar to JSON?

Tags: java, json, parsing

In my project, I am submitting a request to Stripe which returns back an array of cards on file

```
{
data = [{
    address_zip_check = null,
    country = US,
    last4 = 4242,
    funding = credit,
    metadata = {},
    address_country = null,
    address_state = null,
    exp_month = 4,
    exp_year = 2024,
    address_city = null,
    tokenization_method = null,
    cvc_check = pass,
    address_line2 = null,
    address_line1 = null,
    fingerprint = TAw8rdASXn64,
    name = null,
    id = card_1FiwAkASrE1bJO6aaQ,
    address_line1_check = null,
    address_zip = null,
    dynamic_last4 = null,
    brand = Visa,
    object = card,
    customer = cus_GDUhOvTHo9
}, {
    address_zip_check = null,
    country = US,
    last4 = 4444,
    funding = credit,
    metadata = {},
    address_country = null,
    address_state = null,
    exp_month = 4,
    exp_year = 2024,
    address_city = null,
    tokenization_method = null,
    cvc_check = pass,
    address_line2 = null,
    address_line1 = null,
    fingerprint = NW3wMUNiaA8g,
    name = null,
    id = card_1Fj3ZoASrE1bJO6aFu,
    address_line1_check = null,
    address_zip = null,
    dynamic_last4 = null,
    brand = MasterCard,
    object = card,
    customer = cus_GDUhOvTHo9
}], has_more = false, url = /v1/customers / cus_GDUhOvTHo9 / sources, object = list

}
```

The problem is that the `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` does not recognize this as a valid JSON.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

"Expected literal value..."
```

How am I able to parse this information?

Is there a way to modify this string so that it can be recognized as a valid JSON?

Will I have to write my own parsing method?

Comment: _Will I have to write my own parsing method?..._ I guess Yes!

Comment: That the Stripe API returns stuff like this is... weird. Anyway, can you use the [library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java) they provide to interact with their API?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The requests to stripe have to be made using the backend as the middle man. The docs even say that the response will return a valid json. https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/list -- "data": "value" But debugging the response on the backend returns a format like data: 'value' and when the backend sends it to the client, it's formatted data = value. Frustrating

Comment: Is it possible what you're seeing with the `key=value` format is a `toString()` representation of the object structure somehow?  Most `Map#toString` implementations will give this type of representation, e.g.

Comment: @MarkPeters I wrote just that some minutes ago. :-)

Comment: @MarkPeters Yes. The docs threw me off because I was expecting a literal string and not a map, so I logged the return object as a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> returns back an array of cards on **file**

1. The Stripe-API returns valid json [1].
2. I guess the failure occurs in between,e.g. when you serialize the response to a **file**. Make sure you use the proper json tools!
3. Your print looks like an ordinary `Map.toString()`. Just pass the map directly to `new JSONObject(mymap)`.

[1] `curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc:`

Comment: I believe you're right. I think what happened is that the object being returned is a map, but I'm expecting a JSON string. I'll soon change my code accordingly, and see if that works, so I can accept this as the answer if, in fact, it is.